# Is there any way to have a hotkey similar to F5 in SSMS?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

Trying out DataGrip, and I look the tool for SQL editing however I'm so used to SSMS that I'm pretty shocked that they don't have some type of similar hotkey option. All I am after is being able to execute code within my semicolon separators. Your cursor could be above, below, or inside the statement but as long as its within the separators it runs. In DataGrip there is a plethora of options when you go into the execute 1/2/3 menu but none of them seem to allow that functionality.

Was just wondering if I'm missing something or if anyone has figured out a workaround to have that functionality.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This behavior can be changed by selecting an option `When caret inside statement` in *File | Settings | Database | Query Execution*.

Comment: I did try using those options however it's still a little awkward in my opinion. Your cursor has to be on a line of code. If you have a separator a few lines down and your cursor is in-between the separator and the code on an empty line, it will not execute, whereas in SSMS it would. I guess it's just something to get used to but I found it odd that there's no option for something similar.

Comment: Please create a feature request here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE